# How to stop Magento 2 using cookies like recently_viewed_product?

Tags: magento2, cookie, gdpr

According to the GDPR and recent court decisions, technically unnecessary cookies may only be set after the user has given his active consent.

Cookies that are not technically necessary are widely regarded as cookies for tracking, marketing, external media, etc.

Magento 2 sets the following cookies, among others:

- recently_viewed_product
- recently_viewed_product_previous
- recently_compared_product
- recently_compared_product_previous

**First question:**
Does Magento use these cookies to recognize the preferences of the visitor during subsequent page views or sessions and to display products that suit the visitor? In my opinion, these would then be marketing cookies that should not be set until the user actively agrees?

**Second question:**
How can the above mentioned cookies be deactivated without affecting the basic functionality of Magento?

Comment: I can answer the first question. these cookies store the ids of the last viewed products and the products in the compare list. They do not track the visitor. And you could say that they are needed for the functionality of the website.